# Delete folders based on date name in s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have folders in an s3 bucket labeled:

```
date=2021-07-01/
date=2021-07-02/
...
date=2021-07-26/
```

everyday a new folder with the corresponding date is uploaded to the bucket, and I want to delete the folders automatically if they are more than x days old. Currently I have it so that s3 Lifecycle Management is handling it, but it is deleting the folders based off of the last modified date, and occasionally the certain folders need to updated, changing the last modified date and causing them to be deleted much later than the predefined x days.

Is there a way I can do this using a python script that runs daily to check if there are any folders that are too old and deleting them accordingly?

Comment: Yes! Where would you like the script to run -- on your own computer, an EC2 instance, or "automatically in the cloud"? Have you tried writing the script? Let us know if you have a particular problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can do this using a python script that runs daily to check if there are any folders that are too old and deleting them accordingly?

Yes, there is a way. Exact details depend on how big the S3 bucket is, as it requires listing all its content. But thinking positively that the bucket is "small" (use-case specific definition), the usual way would be to:

1. Create a lambda function in python. The function would use **boto3** to query the list of folders in S3, and filter out those for deletion, and delete them.
2. Setup [CloudWatch Event Scheduled rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) to trigger the function every day.